# Change select box value depending other selected option box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am new to Javascript/ Jquery

so my problem is :
i want to change the select/option box text and value depending on the other selected option/box

so for examplemy first option is :

```
<select id="gender">
        <option>Select Your Gender</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

and then one i want to change depending on selected option is :
When its male :

```
<select id="name">
        <option>Select Your Name</option>
        <option value="Male1">Male 1</option>
        <option value="Male2">Male 2</option>
</select>
```

when its female :

```
<select id="name">
        <option>Select Your Name</option>
        <option value="female1">Female 1</option>
        <option value="female2">Female 2</option>
</select>
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: male and female select box values are dynamic or static?

Comment: @Shehary : its static :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go with **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/sryxewv9/1/)**

```
var options=""; //store the dynamic options
$("#gender").on('change',function(){ //add a change event handler to gender select
    var value=$(this).val(); //get its selected value
    options="<option>Select Your Name</option>"
    if(value=="Male") //value ==Male then set male required options
    {
        options+="<option value='Male1'>Male 1</option>"
                +"<option value='Male2'>Male 2</option>";
        $("#name").html(options);
    }
    else if(value=="Female") //else set female required options
    {
        options+='<option value="female1">Female 1</option>'
                 +'<option value="female2">Female 2</option>';
        $("#name").html(options);
    }
    else
        $("#name").find('option').remove() //if first default text option is selected empty the select
});
```

Comment: Hi @GuruprasadRao , this answer my question. because its just a sample data and the actual is the option depend on 2 other thing ( select and radio ) should i create another question or should i update my question ? anyway how is js/jquery actually save value ? i mean in php i can save the value in $value1 and $value2 then add if statement like ( if($value1='') and if($value2 ==''){} , how can i do that in js ? Thanks!

Comment: @bhebhe.. For that you might need to create different question for that. regarding your 2nd doubt like saving option in $value1 etc is quite unclear.. can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Okay, what i mean is in PHP i can do something like : $a = 'value from option 1"; $b = 'value from checkbox'; and then based on that i can define the value of other Select or option like = if($a == 'example 1') and ($b == 'example 2'){ "content "; } else.. etc , how can i do that on JS ? i see you do this "var value=$(this).val();" how can i save value from other #id and then use it in IF statment  > if(value=="Male") and (value2 =="something"); maybe

Comment: For other `id` you might probably want to write one more `event handler` like one written above...

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to have a better HTML architecture to achieve this kind of things. Have each name in one Dropdown only and categorise with some data attribute. When changing the value of *Gender* Dropdown, filter with type and toggle the options. Follow this:

```js
$(function(){
 $("#gender").on("change", function(){
        var $target = $("#name").val(""),
            gender = $(this).val();
        
        $target
            .toggleClass("hidden", gender === "")
            .find("option:gt(0)").addClass("hidden")
         .siblings().filter("[data-type="+gender+"]").removeClass("hidden"); 
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="gender">
        <option value="">Select Your Gender</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select> 
<select id="name" class="hidden">
        <option value="">Select Your Name</option>
        <option value="Male1" data-type="Male">Male 1</option>
        <option value="Male2" data-type="Male">Male 2</option>
        <option value="female1" data-type="Female">Female 1</option>
        <option value="female2" data-type="Female">Female 2</option>
</select>
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/qzxedcut/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i try in fiddle but this display all names instead of just males or females, am i doing it wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a change occurs, use the value of the gender dropdown to populate the names one. We use a for loop to produce more than one option per gender.

```
$('#gender').change(function(){
   if(!this.selectedIndex) return;

   var gender = $(this).val(),
       $name = $('#name').empty(),
       $option = $('<option />').text('Select Your Name').appendTo($name);

   for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
       $option.clone().prop('value', gender + i).text(gender + ' ' + i).appendTo($name);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zL6b7mop/3/)

Comment: Wow.. Awesome @George but you might need to consider while user selects default text as option.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Sure thing.

Comment: Also, name would be real names instead of 1,2,3 things.... Loop would not be a good idea then.

Comment: @AshishKumar Maybe I read the question a little too literally.

Answer (score 1):

### Follow the Practice:

- Do not hardcode options this case.Best practice is get value from Json.
- Then later changes are easy instead of change all codings.
- Build dynamic Dropdowns. Dont Hide and Show.

### HTML

```
<select id="gender">
        <option>Select Your Gender</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>   

    <select id="gtr" name="location" placeholder="Anycity"></select>
```

### Jquery

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var gender = {
        'Male': ['Male1', 'male2'],
        'Female': ['Female1','Female1'],
      
    }
    
    var $gndr = $('#gtr');
    $('#gender').change(function () { debugger
        var GNDR = $(this).val(), gndrs = gender[GNDR] || [];
        
        var html = $.map(gndrs, function(gndr){
            return '<option value="' + gndr + '">' + gndr + '</option>'
        }).join('');
        $gndr.html(html);$gndr.append(new Option("Select Name", "0"));$gndr.val("0");
    });
});
```

### JsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/2pza5/1135/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$("#gender").on("change",function(){
  var sel="";
  if($(this).val() == "Female"){
    sel=' <option>Select Your Name</option>';
       sel+=' <option value="female1">Female 1</option>'
        sel+='<option value="female2">Female 2</option>'
   
    }else{// no other if since you have only two options male/female
     sel= '<option>Select Your Name</option>';
       sel+= '<option value="Male1">Male 1</option>';
       sel+= '<option value="Male2">Male 2</option>';
      }
   $("#name").html(sel);
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="gender">
        <option>Select Your Gender</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>   

<select id="name">
     
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try this way:

Change you jquery:

```
<select id="nameMale">
        <option>Select Your Name</option>
        <option value="Male1">Male 1</option>
        <option value="Male2">Male 2</option>
</select> 

<select id="nameFemale">
        <option>Select Your Name</option>
        <option value="Male1">Male 1</option>
        <option value="Male2">Male 2</option>
</select>
```

Inser this javascript:

```
        <script>
            <![CDATA[
                $(function() {

              $('#nameFemale').hide();
              $('#nameMale').hide();

  function changeGen(val){
     if(val == 'Female'){
         $('#nameFemale').show();
         $('#nameMale').hide();
      }else{
        $('#nameFemale').hide();
        $('#nameMale').show();
      }
  }

  $('#gender').change(function() {
            changeGen($('#gender').val());
    });

    });

 ]]>    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0w9fve3L/2/)

```
$('#gender').change(function (e) {
    var val = $("option:selected", this).val()
    console.log(val);
if(val =='Male'){
    $('#name').find('option.female').hide();
    $('#name').find('option.male').show();
}else if(val =='Female'){
    $('#name').find('option.female').show();
    $('#name').find('option.male').hide();
}else{
    
}
});
```

Added class for each option since it is static.
Then you can hide the option from second select depending on the value of first select

Comment: it is unique @Shehary just hiding and showing stuff

Comment: Heads up for future learner, this example doesn't work on Safari :) I spend quite bit to figure out why it doesnt work on my Mac, then I opened in Chrome everything worked great